# Reading data from table using LIMIT while the order changes

Tags: mysql, sql, messaging

Okay, let me explain.

You know how Facebook Messenger and Discord both have the last messaged friends list? It is a list of all of your friends **order by whoever texted you last**. Now, if you had over 100 people in that list, it would be better to send the list to the client in **chunks of 10**. Once the client reaches the bottom, it asks for the next 10. This can be done with the `LIMIT offset, amount`.

But now, **the problem**. The user might open the messenger, talk to someone for 10 minutes, and then scroll further down in the last messaged friends list. In this case, the table has changed before the user has retrieved the full list. The list in database is now in a different order because someone messaged them in the meanwhile and is now on top of the list, but the client already has the first chunk of the list, but this doesn't contain the people that texted them.

---

In case my explanation was not enough, here's a visual demonstration:

## Visual demo

'Last messaged friends' list in database (ordered by latest timestamp):

- Person 23
- Person 77
- Person 93
- Person 99
- Person 67
- Person 85

User connects, asks for the first 3 entries.
Client now has (ordered by latest timestamp):

- Person 23
- Person 77
- Person 93

'Person 99' messages that user. 'Person 99' is now on top of the list.
'Last messaged friends' list in database (ordered by latest timestamp):

- Person 99
- Person 23
- Person 77
- Person 93
- Person 67
- Person 85

User scrolls down. Client asks for the next 3 entries.
Client now has (ordered by latest timestamp):

- Person 23
- Person 77
- Person 93
- Person 93 (duplicate)
- Person 67
- Person 85

('Person 99' missing)

---

Is this something I could fix/implement with a more advanced SQL query?
If I can't, how could I implement this in other ways?

For information, I have a Socket.io (a.k.a more advanced WebSocket) connection between the server and the client, I can send whatever necessary information thru that.

Comment: Selecting messages by timestamp don't solve this? You keep the last timestamp and then ask by anoter 10 registries >= that timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, **Hector Vido**, for the suggestion. (he made a comment right below my question, **go upvote**)

*"Selecting messages by timestamp don't solve this? You keep the last timestamp and then ask by anoter 10 registries >= that timestamp"*

### Solution

I'll keep the **oldest** and **newest** timestamp in the client side.

If the client scrolls down, I will request 10 entries before the `oldestTimestamp` and then the new `oldestTimestamp` will be the oldest timestamp of the received entries.

Also after every 10 seconds, I could request for entries after the `newestTimestamp`  and then the new `newestTimestamp` will be the newest timestamp of the received entries.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want aggregation to avoid duplicates:

```
select person_id
from messages
group by person_id
order by max(timestamp) desc;
```

Comment: This is basically what I already have. 

But that's where the problem is. When I use LIMIT or OFFSET with it and change the data inside the table between queries, the results are in wrong order, some entries are missing or have duplicates.